# Comparing numbers - Unusual behaviour

Tags: javascript, comparison, numbers

Im getting 2 values from a table and I'd like to compare them. If one is grater than the other, then I alert some error.
The thing is im getting a wrong result... for example I have 1000.00 and 1000000.00 and when I  do 1000.00 > 1000000.00 Im getting a TRUE!, therefore an error, Why is that happening?

Hope someone can help me out here! Thx

```
row = document.getElementById(tabla).rows;
cell = document.getElementById(tabla).rows[0].cells;

for (i=2;i<row.length-1;i++){
    var TotalDist = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tabla).rows[i].cells[cell.length].firstChild.nodeValue).toFixed(2);
    var Total = document.getElementById(tabla).rows[i].cells[cell.length+1].firstChild.nodeValue;

    if(TotalDist>Total)
       alert("Error");
}
```

One of the values is already a float that I get from a db, the other one (TotalDist) is set by the user, so I convert it to float so that they can be compared properly... but it doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert both values to a number (ie use `parseFloat` on both strings) ->

```
row = document.getElementById(tabla).rows;
cell = document.getElementById(tabla).rows[0].cells;

for (i=2;i<row.length-1;i++){
    var TotalDist = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tabla).rows[i].cells[cell.length].firstChild.nodeValue).toFixed(2);
    var Total = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tabla).rows[i].cells[cell.length+1].firstChild.nodeValue);

    if(TotalDist>Total)
       alert("Error");

}
```

When using `nodeValue` a `string` is returned ... [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue)

```
var value = node.nodeValue;
```

> value is a **string** containing the value of the current node

Comment: One of the values is already a float that I get from a db, the other one (TotalDist) is set by the user, so I convert it to float so that they can be compared properly... but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @dan they may well floats in a DB - but they are strings in a `nodeValue` [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nodeValue) > *value is a string containing the value of the current node*

Comment: @ManseUK, Yes you are right, there is no base for `parseFloat` thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal your answer was correct though ... the problem is that the OP required `parseFloat`

Comment: Thank you sr! Yes, the main problem was not converting the other value to float. I didnt know that about nodeValue. Thx again

Comment: @ManseUK, It isn't correct, because it contained wrong syntax. I had to delete it, because I don't need any one to see it here in SO. And I found it confusing to the OP. Since he thought, from his comment, that the problem was that he didn't set the base.